# Stable Diffusion error (not a git repository)

Tags: fatal-error, stable-diffusion

when launching webui.bat, the error

```
venv "M:\\stable-diffusion-webui-master (1)\\stable-diffusion-webui-master\\venv\\Scripts\\Python.exe"
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

first there were errors 9009, then Python, Git not in PATH. I've solved them all, but I can't figure this one out.

I tried to run a neural network in Virtualbox, but there is also the same error. I tried to download python from the official site, but I was given the error "a never version of the python" or something along the way... file not found "launcher.py ".

I decided to install Python from the microsoft store just so I could fix the python bug. when installing git, I ticked 1 or 2 pages, and just left the rest as it is. has anyone encountered such a problem? I can't find anything on the Internet about this. I decided to ask ChatGPT, but he didn't help me.

I'm from Russia and translated it through a translator, maybe something will be unclear [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YwaW.png)

---

I installed python from the Microsoft store, because I have errors from the official site that I can't fix in any way

when installing Git, I checked the boxes in all the cells on page 2. I left the rest as it is.

executed

```
git clone https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui.git
```

Answer (score 1):

The git errors you're seeing are from the auto-updater, and are not the reason the software fails to start. These are probably related to either the wrong working directory at runtime, or moving/deleting things. Git doesn't see its repo metadata. This is a red flag that something is awry with your setup. Missing .git metadata is fatal to Git but not to the web UI startup script. In other words, Git errors don't stop the software from running, they just stop it from self-updating. Notice there is more output after them. The script continues afterwards whether Git succeeded or not.

That python / Torch error at the bottom is the real error that's stopping you here. This is likely from either using the wrong version of Python or having done an incorrect manual installation of PyTorch. There is a note in the repo readme about the Python version requirement. Don't do your own thing, let the automatic dependency installer/updater part of the script do its job. You need to use the exact version of everything that the software was developed against, or things will break. This is a particularly brittle piece of software. The fact that you had trouble installing the standard Python distribution and had to go with a different version from the Microsoft Store instead is another red flag that something is awry. This is very important to get right from the beginning.

There is a document in the repo with instructions. There should not be additional things you have to solve after following those instructions. If there are, something is wrong, and you should start over. Be sure to tell the Python installer to add itself to your PATH - this is a checkbox on the first screen of the installer. What I would do here is uninstall the Python from the Windows store, delete the directory structure you cloned, and start over, following the instructions exactly instead of trying to figure out your own way of doing it. Get one thing working at a time. Get the correct version of Python working in a terminal first, then get Git working, make sure it works in a terminal, clone the files making sure there are no errors, then open a terminal and run the supplied batch file to start it. If you run into issues installing anything along that procedure, that problem must be solved before moving on, because those issues will prevent the steps after them from working.

Installation instructions: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui#automatic-installation-on-windows